# Ngrx after reseting the store, component dispatching an action

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have implemented the Store for my App. After logout I want to reset store. But there is a problem.

Let's assume I have the following State:

```
subjects: {
    subjectsLoaded: true
}
```

In component I'm subscribe to the store like that:

```
 this.store.pipe(
        select(areSubjectsLoaded),
         tap((subjectsLoaded) => {
             if (!subjectsLoaded) {
                 this.store.dispatch(loadSubjects());
                 console.log('Dispatching Subjects because they are not Loaded');
             }
         }),
         filter(subjectsLoaded => subjectsLoaded),
         takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
     ).subscribe();
```

After logout and reseting the store, it will looks like:

```
 subjects: {
    subjectsLoaded: false
}
```

Since I am subscribed to changes in the component, an action dispatch will be made. But I don't know how to prevent this.
 I'm also using `takeUntil`  in order not to receive data after the destroy of the component

There is a small demo:

[image]

For clear the store I'm using metaReducers:

```
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<AppState>[] = [clearState];

export function clearState(reducer: ActionReducer<AppState>): ActionReducer<AppState> {
  return (state: AppState, action: Action): AppState => {
    if (action.type === '[Toolbar] User Logout') {
      console.log('Clear state: ',state);
      state = undefined;
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to use something else than `undefined`, because, as you've seen, you can no longer distinguish 'state has not been initialized' and 'state must reset'.

You could use a `symbol` to differentiate these *states*.

```js
export const RESET_STATE = Symbol('reset state');
```

```js
// your meta-reducer
state = RESET_STATE;

return state;
```

Now you could recognize them this way:

```js
this.store.pipe(
  filter(state => state !== RESET_STATE),
  select(areSubjectsLoaded),
  /* ... */
)
```

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you could create a selector out of that logic and use it in your other selectors as well.

Comment: What  do you think about some Service which has the property with type `Subject`
Also with method that calls `subject.next()`. I will call this method in  `ngOnDestroy` and also in button method that does http request logout then dispatch action logout. And will use `takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)`

Comment: I guess it would work, but you’ll have to be able to identify for which component the service should emit. For example, you might have 2 comps that subscribed to that Subjecf, but you wouldn’t both to unsubscribe when one is destroyed. You could have a method on that service what will add a “filter” operator to the component’s observable

Comment: Hmm,  it make sence. Thank you